# SQL Server Error Handling, Determine if Record Exists, Then Execute Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, try-catch

I have a piece of script I want to execute multiple times every night, based on an uncertain number of items in a table (Random, every night). I would plan to have it execute every 5/10 minutes.

The procedure looks for an item in the 'Master Table' and clones it to other necessary tables.

Basically I could just let the script run and it would fail every time, but I want to be a little smarter than that and save on all the error messages.

How can I first determine whether an item is there to be cloned... and then either execute or abort the script depending on the outcome?

I have tried;

```
BEGIN TRY

--Procedure

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

--Procedure

END CATCH
```

But that seems to just execute anyway, with the errors...

Or perhaps an IF statement would be a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF` would be the way to go:

```
IF EXISTS (/*Statement to check if rows exist*/)
BEGIN

  --Procedure

END
```

If the `IF` condition is not satisfied the procedure will not run. You just need to figure out an appropriate check.

Comment: Ironically I had the words IF & EXISTS in my question title.. :) Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myConditions)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO OtherTable SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myConditions
END
```